# shift/reduce because of a recursion rule

Tags: recursion, bison, flex-lexer, shift-reduce-conflict

I'm trying to write a mini-compiler of a given language using flex & bison.
It was working fine until I found out I forgot about a rule
which has recursion in it, the rule being:

```
 liste_data : liste_data declar | declar;
```

As I added it, I had shift/reduce conflicts which I don't understand. My grammar is not ambiguous

Here's a simplified version of my grammar:

```
s:idf bloc_data mc_end   { printf ("programme juste (lexique+syntaxe)\n"); YYACCEPT;}
;
bloc_data:mc_data liste_data mc_end
|mc_data mc_end
;
liste_data : declar
|liste_data declar
;
declar: liste_const
|liste_type
;
liste_type:liste_type def_type
|def_type
;
def_type:mc_char ':' liste_var ';'
;
liste_var:idf
|liste_var '|' idf
;
liste_const:liste_const constante
|constante
;
constante:mc_const ':' idf affect entier ';'
;
```

It basically says that I could define characters along with constants in the DATA bloc

Here's my .output

```
État 11 conflits: 1 décalage/réduction
État 13 conflits: 1 décalage/réduction


Grammaire

0 $accept: s $end

1 s: idf bloc_data mc_end

2 bloc_data: mc_data liste_data mc_end
3          | mc_data mc_end

4 liste_data: declar
5           | liste_data declar

6 declar: liste_const
7       | liste_type

8 liste_type: liste_type def_type
9           | def_type

10 def_type: mc_char ':' liste_var ';'

11 liste_var: idf
12          | liste_var '|' idf

13 liste_const: liste_const constante
14            | constante

15 constante: mc_const ':' idf affect entier ';'
.
.
.

état 11

7 declar: liste_type .
8 liste_type: liste_type . def_type

mc_char  décalage et aller à l'état 7

mc_char   [réduction par utilisation de la règle 7 (declar)]
$défaut  réduction par utilisation de la règle 7 (declar)

def_type  aller à l'état 20


état 13

6 declar: liste_const .
13 liste_const: liste_const . constante

mc_const  décalage et aller à l'état 8

mc_const  [réduction par utilisation de la règle 6 (declar)]
$défaut  réduction par utilisation de la règle 6 (declar)

constante  aller à l'état 21
```

It says my shift/reduce conflicts are in State 11 & 13 but I couldn't figure out why exactly.
It's supposed to recognize something like this:

```
DATA
CONST: Er=5;
CONST: H=56;
CHAR: Hg|rt;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `liste_const` is just a list of `constante` with no intervening punctuation:

```
constante constante constante constante
```

And a `declar` might be a `liste_const`

What then happens if you have a `liste_data` (which is really a `liste_declar`, no?). That could be a list of lists of `constante`, but there is no way to know where the first list of `constante` ends and the next one begins. So the above could be parsed as

```
<list_const <constante constante>> <list_const <constante>> <list_const <constante>>
```

or

```
<list_const <constante constante constante constante>>
```

or a large number of other possibilities.

The situation with `liste_type` is analogous.

In other words, you don't want a `liste_data` to be a list of lists of constants and types; you want it to be a list of (constant or type).

Personally, I'd just change:

```
declar: def_type | constante;
```

and get rid of `liste_type` and `list_const`.

Comment: oh, it makes sense and I didn't even realize it because I added the liste_data rule after writing the other rules.
Thank you!